# which is best way of send scheduled notification using cloud function to fcm with own server

Tags: c#, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have flutter app and it fetch the data from api when implementing fcm scheduled notification.
I  tried with fcm and flutter local notification to implement scheduled  notification . For that  i listen to `onmessage` callback in `firebasemessaging` package and in notification payload set parameter isSchedule to true then schedule it using flutter local notification but the problem is, it doesn't works on background

And then i try adding parameter  "time_to_live" in the send request body and through this fcm api url https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
   
"to": "/topics/installers",
 
 "notification": {
    "title": "notification title",
    "body": "notification body"
  },

"time_to_live" : 120
}
```

So i have confused with run any scheduler and then call fcm api to an appropriate time

or

From app server call http rest api to add notification datails in firebase cloud firestore and read by every minute using cloud function pub /sub when scheduled time  comes request the fcm api to recieve notification registered or subscribed android & ios device also any other correction in the method

Any other way to schedule in backend and api are written in c#

Comment: Why is this tagged with "php"?

Answer (score 0):

> `time_to_live` This parameter specifies how long (in seconds) the message should be kept in FCM storage if the device is offline. The maximum time to live supported is 4 weeks, and the default value is 4 weeks.  [read more](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

If you need to schedule tasks look at [Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler).